# 2 comboboxes,select one,change another

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, combobox, jquery-easyui

now i have improved the code,and i have a new question,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/color.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //simulate the database
    var data={};
    data.id1=[{value:"id1",text:"aa1"},{value:"id2",text:"aa2"}];
    data.id2=[{value:"id3",text:"aa3"},{value:"id4",text:"aa4"}];
    data.id1.id1=[{value:"id1",text:"aaa1"},{value:"id2",text:"aaa2"}];
    data.id1.id2=[{value:"id3",text:"aaa3"},{value:"id4",text:"aaa4"}];
    data.id2.id1=[{value:"id5",text:"aaa5"},{value:"id6",text:"aaa6"}];
    data.id2.id2=[{value:"id7",text:"aaa7"},{value:"id8",text:"aaa8"}];
    $(function(){
        var c1id;
        $("#c1").combobox("loadData",[{value:"id1",text:"a1"},{value:"id2",text:"a2"}]);
        //change c2 box when c1 on select
        $("#c1").combobox({
            onSelect:function(record){
                c1id=record.value;
                $("#c2").combobox("clear");
                $("#c2").combobox("loadData",data[record.value]);
                try{var c2data=$("#c2").combobox("getData");//c2data.length is 0?
                value=c2data[0].text;
                $("#c2").combobox("select",value);}
                catch(e){

                }
            }
        }) 
        $("#c2").combobox({
            onSelect:function(record){
                $("#c3").combobox("clear");
                $("#c3").combobox("loadData",data[c1id][record.value]);
                try{var c2data=$("#c3").combobox("getData");//c2data.length is 0?
                value=c2data[0].text;
                $("#c3").combobox("select",value);}
                catch(e){

                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="c1" class="easyui-combobox">
<input id="c2" class="easyui-combobox">
<input id="c3" class="easyui-combobox">
</body>
</html>
```

now i have improved the code,and i have a new question,

now 3 combo,and i select "a1" in 1st combo,the "aa1" auto selected in second combo,but "aaa1" not been selected in the third combo .
cause

```
$("#c2").combobox({
        onSelect:function(record){
```

the `record` here is undefined.
why?
this line

```
$("#c2").combobox("select",value);}
```

will trigger #c2 onselect event,but the record parameter is undefined.
so i can not auto select the first item of third combobox when i selected the first combobox.

---

### Here is the question before:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/color.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //simulate the database
    var data={};
    data.id1=[{value:"id1",text:"aa1"},{value:"id2",text:"aa2"}];
    data.id2=[{value:"id3",text:"aa3"},{value:"id4",text:"aa4"}];
    $(function(){
        $("#c1").combobox("loadData",[{value:"id1",text:"a1"},{value:"id2",text:"a2"}]);
        //change c2 box when c1 on select
        $("#c1").combobox({
            onSelect:function(record){
                $("c2").combobox("clear");
                $("c2").combobox("loadData",data[record.value]);
                var c2data=$("#c2").combobox("getData");//c2data.length is 0?
                value=c2data[0].text;
                $("c2").combobox("select",value);
            }
        }) 
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="c1" class="easyui-combobox">
<input id="c2" class="easyui-combobox">
<input id="c3" class="easyui-combobox">
</body>
</html>
```

There are 2 comboboxes,when the item of the first comboxbox been selected,change the data of second.And select the 1st item of the

second combobox.
after page loaded,i selected "a1" of the first comobox,
this line has been executed:
var c2data=$("#c2").combobox("getData");
but then c2data.length is 0?
why?

Comment: `$("c2")` ==> `$("#c2")`. Missing ID selector `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tushar pointed out in a comment, it looks like it's just a typo. You left the hash-mark out of the ID selector for `c2` in a few places.

```js
//simulate the database
var data = {};
data.id1 = [
  { value: "id1", text: "aa1" },
  { value: "id2", text: "aa2" }
];

data.id2 = [
  { value: "id3", text: "aa3" },
  { value: "id4", text: "aa4" }
];
    
$(function() {
  $("#c1").combobox("loadData", [
      { value: "id1", text: "a1" },
      { value: "id2", text: "a2" }
  ]);
  
  //change c2 box when c1 on select
  $("#c1").combobox({
    onSelect: function(record) {
      $("#c2").combobox("clear");
      $("#c2").combobox("loadData", data[record.value]);
      var c2data = $("#c2").combobox("getData"); //c2data.length is 0?
      value = c2data[0].text;
      $("#c2").combobox("select", value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/color.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input id="c1" class="easyui-combobox">
<input id="c2" class="easyui-combobox">
<input id="c3" class="easyui-combobox">
```

Comment: i improve the code,3 combos now ,and i have a new question,i writed it above

Comment: @heheyou post a new question rather than modifying your original question.